# Why is my tkinter panedwindow not stretching all the way to the bottom of the window?

Tags: python, tkinter

From looking at this for a few days, I don't understand is why the pandedwindow widget is not all the way down to the top of the bottom frame.  If I block out the frame portion, the PanedWindow goes all the way to the bottom of the window.

Please feel free to criticize or give comments on how I can improve my program in terms of using class.

```
import tkinter as t

def main():
    root = t.Tk()
    root.geometry("350x470")
    root.config(background="LightBlue4")
    root.title("basic window")
    app = Application (root)
    root.mainloop()

class Application():

    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.window = parent

        self.panes=t.PanedWindow(self.window, sashwidth=3)
        self.panes.pack(fill=t.BOTH, expand="yes")


        self.frame1=t.Frame(self.window, bg="yellow", bd=2,     relief=t.RIDGE)   
        self.frame1.pack(anchor=t.S, fill=t.X, expand=1)

        self.createWidgets()


    def createWidgets(self):

        self.entry=t.Entry(self.frame1, width=25)
        self.entry.pack(side=t.LEFT, expand=1)
        self.label2=t.Label(self.frame1, text="Update ", fg = "light  green", bg = "dark green", font = "Helvetica 16 bold italic" , bd=2,  relief=t.RAISED)
        self.label2.pack(side=t.LEFT, fill=t.X, padx=5)
        self.label3=t.Label(self.frame1, text="Quit", fg = "blue", bg = "yellow", font = "Verdana 12 bold" , bd=2, relief=t.RAISED)
        self.label3.pack(side=t.LEFT, fill=t.X, padx=5)

        self.left = t.Label(self.window, text="Left Pane", bd=4, bg="tan",  relief=t.FLAT)
        self.left.pack()

        self.right = t.Label(self.window, text="Right Pane", bd=4, bg="light cyan", relief=t.FLAT)
        self.right.pack()

        self.panes.add(self.left, stretch="always")
        self.panes.add(self.right )
        self.panes.sash_place(0,120,0)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Answer (score 0):

The paned window does not extend the full vertical height because it is sharing space with `self.frame1`. Both have been packed with the option to expand into the available space, so they end up each taking half.

It you turn expansion off on `self.frame1`, the paned window will take all of the available space:

```
self.frame1.pack(anchor=t.S, fill=t.X, expand=False)
```

Comment: Thanks Bryan.  It works now.  I need to revisit the expand feature on the frame widget.  I have being reading some of your comments on other posts regarding tkinter and It has being good to my learning.  Appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't understand is why the pandedwindow widget is not all the way
> down to the top of the bottom frame.

## Why?

That is because the way you packed `self.frame1` and `self.panes` places these 2 widgets  on top of each other. That is what you can see when comment this line: `#self.createWidgets()` :

[image]

## How to resolve this problem?

If you want the PaneWindow widget to stretch down, you will need to pack `self.frame1` and `self.panes` side by side using the [`side`](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_pack.htm) option:

```
self.panes.pack(fill=t.BOTH, expand="yes", side = t.LEFT)
self.frame1.pack(anchor=t.S, fill=t.X, expand=1, side = t.LEFT)
```

**Result:**

[image]

## Better options:

1. As you have many widgets to manage, it is better to use the [`grid()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/grid.htm) layout manager instead of `pack()`.
2. For `self.label2` and `self.label3` use the [`Button()`](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm) widget instead.

Comment: Hi Bill, thanks again.  This is the stage 2 of another post that you are helping me, which I am still reading.  I will respond as soon as I finish the recommended reading.